# Return value if date falls in between two dates in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Employees have a certain time frame to complete an action and get a result. The time frame may crossover from one day to the next. They may have to complete the action more than once per day. I need to match the action datetime to the time frame and keep all the rows in the source table.

Source Table:

Empl ID | Start DateTime | End DateTime

123     | 9/30 10:00 PM  | 10/1 1:00 AM

456     | 10/1 7:00 AM   | 10/1 10:00 AM

456     | 10/1 5:00 PM   | 10/1 10:00 PM

Lookup Table:

Empl ID | Action DateTime | Result

123     | 9/30 11:00 PM   | A

456     | 10/1 9:30 AM    | B

456     | 10/1 11:15 PM   | B

End Result:

Empl ID | Start DateTime | End DateTime  | Action DateTime | Result

123     | 9/30 10:00 PM  | 10/1 1:00 AM  | 9/30 11:00 PM   | A

456     | 10/1 7:00 AM   | 10/1 10:00 AM | 10/1 9:30 AM    | B

456     | 10/1 5:00 PM   | 10/1 10:00 PM | null            | null

I have tried the following code but it is abysmally slow:

```
let
    Source = #"SourceTable",
    LBuffered = Table.Buffer(LookupTable),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "LookupTable", (#"SourceTable") => Table.SelectRows(LBuffered, each #"SourceTable"[Empl ID] = [Empl ID] and #"SourceTable"[Compliance StartDateTime] <= [Action DateTime] and #"SourceTable"[End DateTime] >= [Action DateTime])),
    #"Expanded LookupTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "LookupTable", {"Action DateTime",  "Result"}, {"Action DateTime", "Result"})

(other code)
```

Is there another way I'm not thinking of to speed up this process?

Comment: Hard to tell without the complete picture (for example how many records there are, where are the tables stored, what transformations are happening at the source and lookup tables)

Comment: @ricardiodiaz the "source table" and "lookup table" are each in their own query that i thought to combine in a "end result" query. There could be thousands of records per day. I'm testing this on one week of 27,000 source table records. I create the start and end times on the source table through a simple custom formula (shift time + or - 2 hours).

Comment: Where do they come from? sql, csv, excel?

Comment: You most likely have other transformations. On my end, applying the query that you have to 45k records takes less than 1 sec. It's probably better to review each step and see where is the bottleneck.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz they come from excel and csv. I'm combining CSV files for each day into one query if that makes a difference. All my power query knowledge is self-taught so sometimes it's hard to know what I don't know.

Comment: @ricardodiaz is there a good way to determine what it bottlenecking? Not sure how to approach because it'll be 10 minutes and the query will still be loading to the worksheet.

Comment: What happens if you preview it step by step (you can comment steps so they don't run in the results). What step takes more time?

Answer (score 0):

I think join could be faster. In my example the DateTime-Columns are TEXT, so I converted them to DateTime. If your source has DateTime-Columns you haven't to do this step and save time.

I create a list for all relevant dates per 'Empl ID' for every 15 Minutes.
(In your Lookup-Table examples there are time in 15 Min. step, you can change the M-Code to every Minute if necessary )

```
/*Source Table*/

let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source_Table"]}[Content],
    Custom_StartDateTimeNew = Table.AddColumn(Quelle, "Start DateTimeNew", each 
        #datetime(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), 
                    Number.From(Text.BeforeDelimiter([#"Start DateTime "], "/")), 
                    Number.From(Text.BetweenDelimiters([#"Start DateTime "], "/", " ")), 
                    Time.Hour(Time.From(Text.AfterDelimiter([#"Start DateTime "], " "))), 
                    Time.Minute(Time.From(Text.AfterDelimiter([#"Start DateTime "], " "))), 0)
        , type datetime),
    
    Custom_EndDateTimeNew = Table.AddColumn(Custom_StartDateTimeNew, "End DateTimeNew", each 
        #datetime(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
                    Number.From(Text.BeforeDelimiter([#"End DateTime"], "/")), 
                    Number.From(Text.BetweenDelimiters([#"End DateTime"], "/", " ")), 
                    Time.Hour(Time.From(Text.AfterDelimiter([#"End DateTime"], " "))), 
                    Time.Minute(Time.From(Text.AfterDelimiter([#"End DateTime"], " "))), 0)
        , type datetime),
    
    Custom_ListDateTime = Table.AddColumn(Custom_EndDateTimeNew, "List DateTime", each 
        List.DateTimes([Start DateTimeNew], 
                        (Number.From([End DateTimeNew] - [Start DateTimeNew]))*96+1, 
                        #duration(0,0,15,0))),
    Expand_ListDateTime = Table.ExpandListColumn(Custom_ListDateTime, "List DateTime")
in
    Expand_ListDateTime
```

Lookup:

```
/*Lookup Table*/

let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Lookup_Table"]}[Content],
    #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"Empl ID ", Int64.Type}, {"Action DateTime", type text}, {"Result", type text}}),
    Custom_ActionDateTimeNew = Table.AddColumn(#"Geänderter Typ", "Action DateTimeNew", each 
        #datetime(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
                    Number.From(Text.BeforeDelimiter([#"Action DateTime"], "/")), 
                    Number.From(Text.BetweenDelimiters([#"Action DateTime"], "/", " ")), 
                    Time.Hour(Time.From(Text.AfterDelimiter([#"Action DateTime"], " "))), 
                    Time.Minute(Time.From(Text.AfterDelimiter([#"Action DateTime"], " "))), 0))
in
    Custom_ActionDateTimeNew
```

Result

```
/*Result Table*/
let
    Quelle = Table.NestedJoin(Source_Table, {"Empl ID ", "List DateTime"}, Lookup_Table, {"Empl ID ", "Action DateTimeNew"}, "Lookup_Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    Expand_Lookup_Table = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Quelle, "Lookup_Table", {"Action DateTime", "Result"}, {"Action DateTime", "Result"}),
    RemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Expand_Lookup_Table,{"Empl ID ", "Start DateTime ", "End DateTime", "Action DateTime", "Result"}),
    #"Gruppierte Zeilen" = Table.Group(RemoveOtherColumns, {"Empl ID ", "Start DateTime ", "End DateTime"}, {{"Action DateTime", each List.Max([Action DateTime]), type nullable text}, {"Result", each List.Max([Result]), type nullable text}})
in
    #"Gruppierte Zeilen"
```

[image]